# maatwebsite/excel Laravel file_put_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory

Tags: laravel

I am trying to import an excel sheet of about 100,000 rows into my database. I am using maatwebsite/excel library in Laravel.

whenever I try to upload the excel sheet, I get the error

**file_put_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory**

```
public function importData(Request $request)
{
    try {
        Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file('file'));
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Record Imported Successfully');
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Can someone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2722), the solution is update your `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` like below:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```